# Significance of fixed effects in negative binomial mixed model using mgcv gam

Tags: anova, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I am using `gam` from the `mgcv` package to analyze a dataset with 24 entries :

```
ran  f1     f2   y
1   3000    5   545
1   3000    10  1045
1   10000   5   536
1   10000   10  770
2   3000    5   842
2   3000    10  2042
2   10000   5   615
2   10000   10  1361
3   3000    5   328
3   3000    10  1028
3   10000   5   262
3   10000   10  722
4   3000    5   349
4   3000    10  665
4   10000   5   255
4   10000   10  470
5   3000    5   680
5   3000    10  1510
5   10000   5   499
5   10000   10  1422
6   3000    5   628
6   3000    10  2062
6   10000   5   499
6   10000   10  2158
```

The data has two fixed effects (`f1` and `f2`) and one random effect (`ran`). The dependent data is `y`. Because the dependent data `y` represents counts and is overdispersed, I am using a negative binomial model.

The `gam` model and its `summary` output is as follows:

```
library(mgcv)
summary(gam(y ~ f1 * f2 + s(ran, bs = "re"), data = df2, family = nb, method = "REML"))

Family: Negative Binomial(27.376) 
Link function: log 

Formula:
y ~ f1 * f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.500e+00  3.137e-01  17.533  < 2e-16 ***
f1          -3.421e-05  3.619e-05  -0.945    0.345    
f2           1.760e-01  3.355e-02   5.247 1.55e-07 ***
f1:f2        2.665e-07  4.554e-06   0.059    0.953    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(ran) 4.726      5  85.66  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.866   Deviance explained = 93.6%
-REML = 185.96  Scale est. = 1         n = 24
```

The Wald test from `summary` gives very high significance for `f2` (`P = 1.55e-07`). However, when I test the significance of `f2` by comparing two different models using anova, I get dramatically different results:

```
anova(gam(y ~ f1 * f2 + s(ran, bs = "re"), data = df2, family = nb, method = "ML"),
gam(y ~ f1 + s(ran, bs = "re"), data = df2, family = nb, method = "ML"),
test="Chisq")

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: y ~ f1 * f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")
Model 2: y ~ f1 + s(ran, bs = "re")
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev      Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1    14.843     18.340                          
2    16.652     21.529 -1.8091   -3.188   0.1752
```

f2 is no longer significant. The models were changed from REML to ML, as recommended for evaluation of fixed effects.

If the interaction is preserved, f2 still remains insignificant using anova:

```
anova(gam(y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 + s(ran, bs = "re"), data = df2, family = nb, method = "ML"),
gam(y ~ f1 + f1:f2 + s(ran, bs = "re"), data = df2, family = nb, method = "ML"),
test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: y ~ f1 + f2 + f1:f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")
Model 2: y ~ f1 + f1:f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev       Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1    14.843     18.340                           
2    15.645     19.194 -0.80159 -0.85391   0.2855
```

I would be very grateful for advice on which of these approaches is more appropriate. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WARNING section of `?anova.gam` says:

> If models `a` and `b` differ only in terms with no un-penalized components (such as random effects) then p values from `anova(a,b)` are unreliable, and usually much too low.

I'd guess that the p-value is unreliable but in this instance you have a situation where the opposite case to that expected is observed - p-values are much larger.

However, I think you aren't comparing the right models. Unless you know what you are doing, the principle of marginality should be observed when comparing models with interactions.

So I would compare a model with main effects of `f1` and `f2` with a model that included these main effect *and* their interaction.

- model 1: `y ~ f1 * f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")`
- model 2: `y ~ f1 + f2 + s(ran, bs = "re")`

Unless there is somethign you aren't telling us about how your models are setup, you shouldn't include a higher-order term without including the lower order terms that are found in the higher order term. For example, you have `f1 + f1:f2` and `f2` is found in the second order term but is not found as a first order term in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gavin, and also all your efforts bringing the gift of fire that is mgcv::gam to the masses. I read up on principle of marginality and decided it was best to do post-hoc testing of f1 at the two levels of f2, and f2 at the two levels of f1 using multcomp::glht. With this, f1 is somewhat significant (P ~ 0.04 at the two levels), f2 highly significant (P ~ 1e-15 both levels), and the interaction non-significant (P = 0.96).

Comment: Also, I accepted your answer but have insufficient Stack Overflow powers for the little green arrow to become manifest.

Comment: @Bob. I think your ability to add a checkmark is one time restricted, not rep-restricted. Pretty sure you can do it now. (But maybe not also add an upvote.)

Comment: Many thanks for your input, @42- (whose many comments I have previously had the honor of enjoying and profiting from). As you suggested, I can now add the pretty green checkmark (but not the upvote), and have indeed done so. Many thanks again!